# ERROR: extension "btree_gist" must be installed in schema "heroku_ext"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

Heroku made a change to the way postgressql [extensions gets installed](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search#installing-extensions)

This is screwing up new rails review apps in heroku with the following error.

ERROR:  extension "btree_gist" must be installed in schema "heroku_ext"

This is screwing up things as I need to drop existing extensions and re-enable with heroku_ext schema. I use bin/rails db:structure:load which is before running a migration.

Also the structure.sql is going to diverge as heroku add the schema in review app and we need to run the creation manually in local dev machine.

Does anybody came across this issue?

Comment: Not RoR, but this question is also discussing this Heroku PostgreSQL change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73206939/heroku-postgres-postgis-django-releases-fail-with-relation-spatial-ref-sys

Comment: Did you contact Heroku?

Comment: We've encountered into the same issue recently. Filed a support ticket, but yet no respond from Heroku.

Comment: We did contact heroku and waiting for their response.

Comment: Filed tickets, got our enterprise support rep involved, they've been very slow to respond, and no details. This is impacting our BI pipeline, and I wish they'd offer an option to disable this new "feature" for databases until they resolve these issues.

Answer (score 14):

I have developed a monkey-patch solution that is, well, definitely a hack, but better than pre-dating migrations, or deleting lines from schema.rb.

Put this in `config/initializers`. I called mine `_enable_extension_hack.rb` to make sure it gets loaded early.

```
module EnableExtensionHerokuMonkeypatch
  # Earl was here
  def self.apply_patch!
    adapter_const = begin
      Kernel.const_get('ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter')
    rescue NameError => ne
      puts "#{self.name} -- #{ne}"
    end

    if adapter_const
      patched_method = adapter_const.instance_method(:enable_extension)

      # Only patch this method if it's method signature matches what we're expecting
      if 1 == patched_method&.arity
        adapter_const.prepend InstanceMethods
      end
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def enable_extension(name)
      name_override = name

      if schema_exists?('heroku_ext')
        puts "enable_extension -- Adding SCHEMA heroku_ext"
        name_override = "#{name}\" SCHEMA heroku_ext -- Ignore trailing double quote"
      end

      super name_override
    end
  end
end

EnableExtensionHerokuMonkeypatch.apply_patch!
```

What does it do? It monkey-patches the `enable_extension` call that's causing the problem in `db/schema.rb`. Specifically, if it finds that there is a schema called `"heroku_ext"`, it will *decorate* the parameter given to `enable_extension` so that the SQL that gets executed specifies the `"heroku_ext"` schema. Like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pg_stat_statements" SCHEMA heroku_ext -- Ignore trailing double quote"
```

Without this hack, the generated SQL looks like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pg_stat_statements"
```

Comment: Actually an elegant solution that avoids changing the migration files and prevents the need to have a heroku_ext schema created locally

Comment: For anyone facing loading issues due to `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter` name error, you can include line in the top of the patch:

`require "active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter"`

Answer (score 12):

That's cleaner way of patching `schema.rb`

```rb
# config/initializers/patch_enable_extension.rb

require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

# NOTE: patch for https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2446
module EnableExtensionHerokuPatch
  def enable_extension(name, **)
    return super unless schema_exists?("heroku_ext")

    exec_query("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"#{name}\" SCHEMA heroku_ext").tap { reload_type_map }
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class PostgreSQLAdapter
      prepend EnableExtensionHerokuPatch
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the right answer IMO. I did, however, need a `require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'` at the top.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Simple and direct! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Here’s the official changelog as a reference https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2446

You'll need to do the unthinkable because of the recent heroku changes and modify past migration files for your review apps to work with the new Heroku system for extensions.

1. Add a predated, or at the top of the first migration file `connection.execute 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS heroku_ext'`
2. Potentially also add to the `database.yml` a schema_search_path that includes `heroku_ext` (or set it to `public,heroku_ext` if you hadn't customized it)
3. Grep all `enable_extension('extension_name')`
4. Replace them all by a `connection.execute('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "extension_name" WITH SCHEMA "heroku_ext"`)
5. Pray that is enough to fix the problem

After making those changes we still had to contact heroku support because of, in order:

- a `pgaudit stack is not empty` error

  - The fix here was to run a maintenance twice (because the postgres add-on which was scheduled for maintenance pre-dated the schema/extension changes change)
- a `ERROR:  function pg_stat_statements_reset(oid, oid, bigint) does not exist` error

  - The fix here was a manual intervention from heroku on the databases. It was caused by heroku trying to run a `pg_stat_statements_reset` each time a schema is created.

Comment: For existing database (e.g. on prod), should new extensions be installed in public or heroku_ext?

Comment: @sguha all new extensions in existing databases should be created in the heroku_ext schema. (I’ve added a link to the heroku changelog that explains all of this)

Comment: For 4, we should use "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS" because `enable_extension` uses that statement.

Answer (score 1):

This hack seems to be working for me. The following script runs in the postdeploy step in app.json.

```
#!/bin/bash -xue
# Create extensions in the schema where Heroku requires them to be created
# The plpgsql extension has already been created before this script is run
heroku pg:psql -a $HEROKU_APP_NAME -c 'create extension if not exists citext schema heroku_ext'
heroku pg:psql -a $HEROKU_APP_NAME -c 'create extension if not exists pg_stat_statements schema heroku_ext'

# Remove enable_extension statements from schema.rb before loading it, since
# even 'create extension if not exists' fails when the schema is not heroku_ext
mv db/schema.rb{,.orig}
grep -v enable_extension db/schema.rb.orig > db/schema.rb
rails db:schema:load
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Tuesday 16th August 2022, we've found that a patch no longer seems to be needed and `enable_extension` appears to be working seamlessly as normal without the need to explicitly specify a schema.

When I mentioned this in our ongoing thread with Heroku Support, they said that some of their fixes around the `heroku_ext` change may have been released at the time of resolving https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2450, but that there are still further fixes in development and yet to be released - so my guess is that this particular issue is one on those that has been fixed!

Comment: I tried running pg:copy today and I'm still running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The answer supplied by dzirtusss got me most of the way there, the last thing I had to do to get this working for my Rails application was to edit the search paths in `config/database.yml` to include `heroku_ext`. This is what I appended to my default configuration.

```
# config/database.yml
default:
  schema_search_path: public,heroku_ext
```

After adding the initialization script and the database.yml edit, I was able to successfully run a `heroku pg:copy` from one application to another with no errors and no unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has introduced an `--extensions` flag recently, which helps as a workaround. See this [FAQ](https://help.heroku.com/ZOFBHJCJ/heroku-postgres-extension-changes-faq).

For example, if you're using the `btree_gist` extension, you can use `heroku run pg:reset --extensions 'btree_gist' --app YOUR_APP_NAME` before running your migrations, they should then work without any changes in your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the Heroku datastore durability tool to create a backup on the
   source database or `heroku pg:backups:capture -a <SOURCE_APP>`.
2. Determine which pg extensions the database uses (can check from psql
   with \dx)
3. create a comma-separated string of the extensions (e.g.:`fuzzystrmatch,pg_stat_statements,pg_trgm,pgcrypto,plpgsql,unaccent,uuid-ossp'`)
4. Make sure your Heroku CLI is updated to at least version 7.63.0 (use
   `heroku update` to update)
5. Run this:

   ```
   heroku pg:backups:restore $(heroku pg:backups public-url -a <SOURCE_APP>) DATABASE_URL --extensions '<EXTENSIONS>' -a <TARGET_APP>
   ```
6. Reset dynos on the TARGET_APP