# How to adjust an Elixir application to work with PostgreSQL extensions on Heroku placed in `heroku_ext` schema

Tags: heroku, elixir, heroku-postgres

I have run in to this DB error message during the creation of a Heroku review app:

```
psql:/priv/repo/structure.sql:25: ERROR:  Extensions can only be created on heroku_ext schema
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at RAISE
```

This was caused by [changes to PostgreSQL extension schema management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2446) made by Heroku which are effective since 01 August 2022.

The question is now how to best adjust an Elixir application to comply with the new Heroku rules? In particular when:

1. You create extensions in migrations;
2. You create extensions in `priv/repo//structure.sql` for `mix ecto.load`;
3. In your code you use functions from those extensions (e.g. `UNACCENT()`).

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the particular points:

1. If you create extensions in migrations – e.g. using `execute "create extension if not exists \"uuid-ossp\"", "";` – you don't need to do anything: they will be created in the `heroku_ext` schema.
2. Make sure all your `CREATE EXTENSION` calls use `WITH SCHEMA heroku_ext`. E.g. `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent WITH SCHEMA heroku_ext;`.
3. To let PostgreSQL know that it should search also in the `heroku_ext` schema for extensions and therein present functions add `after_connect: {Postgrex, :query!, _query_args = ["SET search_path TO public,heroku_ext", []]}` to your Repo config (more: [1], [2]) or adjust it to have `heroku_ext` if you already had a custom `search_path`. E.g.

```
config :app, App.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  # ...
  after_connect: {Postgrex, :query!, _query_args = ["SET search_path TO public,heroku_ext", []]}
```

Without the above you would need to call functions with a prefix/namespace qualifier e.g. `heroku_ext.UNACCENT()` which would break an app if it would have extensions placed in different schemas.

After doing those the review app should be created successfully and also the production environment – in which extensions might be still placed in different schemas (e.g. `public` or `pg_catalog`) – will still work fine.

---

It's helpful to connect to the review apps' or staging/production apps' DBs and list the extensions they have e.g.:

```
% heroku pg:psql -a app-pr-123
app-pr-123::DATABASE=> \dx
                            List of installed extensions
   Name    | Version |   Schema   |                   Description                   
-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql   | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 unaccent  | 1.1     | heroku_ext | text search dictionary that removes accents
 uuid-ossp | 1.1     | heroku_ext | generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)
(3 rows)
```

---

References

- [1] https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/multi-tenancy-with-query-prefixes.html
- [2] [What is the schema search path search_path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/408011)
- Same problem described for Ruby/Rails apps [ERROR: extension "btree_gist" must be installed in schema "heroku_ext"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214844/error-extension-btree-gist-must-be-installed-in-schema-heroku-ext)