# Error copying Postgres database in Heroku

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I've been using the same command to copy my Heroku Postgres database from my production environment to my development without a hitch, until today:

`heroku pg:copy <production-app>::DATABASE DATABASE --app <development-app>`

```
Starting copy of DATABASE to DATABASE... done
Copying... !
 ▸    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 ▸
 ▸
 ▸    pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 36
 ▸    pg_restore finished with errors
 ▸    waiting for pg_dump to complete
 ▸    pg_dump finished successfully
 ▸
 ▸    Run heroku pg:backups:info <redacted> for more details.
```

Then if I run the command for more details, I get:

```
▸    Not found.
```

Comment: which plan you are - free? maybe you can find the problem in documentation - if there are some limitations listed

Comment: If you're using any postgres extensions it's almost certainly related to a change Heroku made to how they handle postgres extensions. There's lots more discussions and possible workarounds in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73206939/heroku-postgres-postgis-django-releases-fail-with-relation-spatial-ref-sys

Comment: @DougHarris Ah that might be it since I'm using `citext`

Comment: I'm also using `citext` :-(

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a solution because it didn't fully work for me, but possibly a place to start.

Rather than use `pg:copy`, I tried to break it into a few steps.

First, I did a dump from the source database:

`pg_dump -O -f dumpfile.sql $(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a <my-app>`

Next, I manually edited the file. I changed:

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA public;` to

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA heroku_ext;`

and I replaced any references to `public.citext` with `heroku_ext.citext`.

Last, I loaded the edited dump file:

`psql $(heroku config:get HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL -a <my-app>) < dumpfile.sql`

It didn't fail in the same way as `pg:copy` but there were other errors that prevented my app from running properly. I haven't yet had the chance to dig deeper.

**Update:** Heroku support suggested this workaround to me that is somewhat similar but I've not had a chance to try it yet:

> The best path forward is going to be moving those extensions into the heroku_ext schema.
>
> To fix the `pg:copy` upgrade method, you will need to correct the source system to be in the heroku_ext. To do this you will want to capture a backup, modify the backup file and restore using the modified backup file.
>
> Because of the uniqueness around each customers' database, we are not able to automate these steps behind the scenes.
>
> Steps for doing so
>
> 1. Download Your Backup https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#downloading-your-backups
> 2. Convert dump file to .sql file `pg_restore -f <output-file-name> <input-file-name>`
> 3. Modify the CREATE EXTENSION commands to use WITH SCHEMA heroku_ext. You may need to modify the dependencies suggested above.
> 4. Restore the backup using pg_restore
> 5. Take a new backup pg:backup:capture on the corrected database so the next restore comes from a corrected